# mod_rewrite doesn't work in Linux Mint localhost

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a CMS and trying to convert post links to pretty ones like so:

Original Link:

```
http://localhost/index.php?id=13&category=Uncategorized&title=just-a-link
```

Converted Link:

```
http://localhost/13/Uncategorized/just-a-test
```

I'm using Apache2 on Linux Mint and my website is located in:

```
var/www/html
```

I loaded mod_rewrite using `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then restarted apache2.

my apache2 config file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` inside it i have:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride All
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

and here is my .htaccess file located in `var/www/html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /single.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

I have also restarted apache2 several times, but it just doesn't work.

Here is the loaded modules from phpinfo, (you can see that mod_rewrite is loaded)

```
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

If i directly take $_GET values from url without mod rewrite it works but with pretty urls I can't get $_GET values anymore.

not pretty:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM1Pr.png

pretty:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLCGl.png

Comment: I usually find 50% of this kind of these "why in hell is it not working" errors are related with SELinux. Did you check it?

Comment: @Amarnasan No, how do i do that?

Comment: It depends on your linux flavor, but take a looke here http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Comment: @Amarnasan I disabled SELINUX and problem still exists.